# How to change cmd python from anaconda to default python?

Tags: python, anaconda, default

windows power shell or cmd uses anaconda python instead of the default windows installation
how to make them use the default python installation?

my os is win 8.1
python 3.6
anaconda python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the environment path variable of your default python interpreter in system properties.

or if this doesn't work do:

in cmd  `C:\Python27\python.exe yourfilename.py`

in the command first part is your interpreter location and second is your file name

Comment: iam using the cmd alot so it will be inconvenient to write the path every time
and i ve tried to change env var but nothing happen

Comment: @AhmedElshorbagy have you removed the path of the anaconda interpreter from environment  path variables

Comment: yes i did thanks at first it didn't work but after couple of trials it worked
thanks