# Prevent anaconda from being default python - Windows 10

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I have both Anaconda and Python 3.7 installed on my computer. I want to install `pip` packages onto my default Python 3.7, but I would like to keep Anaconda functional for other purposes.

Right now my pip is located at `C:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip`, but what I want is `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe`.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586049/how-to-change-cmd-python-from-anaconda-to-default-python), but I have no idea which item in my PATH to change. I do not want to screw up my Anaconda install.

Comment: _I want to install pip packages onto my default Python..._ I’m curious, is there any particular reason why?

Comment: @AMC, I have a `virtualenv` in Anaconda that needs some older versions of packages, but I need newer versions of those same packages for other projects, and so I'd like to be able to install them, too. I know I could just create another `virtualenv`, but I'd rather not if I can avoid it.

Comment: Virtualenv, like inside of another Conda environment? _I know I could just create another virtualenv, but I’d rather not if I can avoid it._ Why...? Doesn’t that defeat the purpose of using virtual environments? What happens when you get a third project?

Comment: Well, the truth is I don't know much about virtualenvs, but I use it for [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) development. I just followed the instructions to install it via `virtualenv`, and it did all the very specific dependencies for me. I know about python, but I had no experience with Anaconda, so I only really use Anaconda for that. I try to stick to straight python as much as I can.

Comment: When you say virtualenv, are you referring to the specific tool, or the concept of virtual environments? Learning the basics of Conda is very simple, by the way, you really should use it. The [official documentation](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) is nice. By the way, which packages do you need newer versions of?

Comment: Sorry, not packages, just python itself. Manim needs 3.7 otherwise it throws lots of errors (I don't know why, but that's the consensus in the issues section on GitHub), and I like 3.8 because I like using two main advantages: the `:=` "walrus" operator, and the new `math.dist` for Euclidean distance rather than Pythagorean-theroeming that stuff. And also just the fact that it's the newest version. In terms of your first question, I will check it out, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Are you sure that it will work with Python 3.8? Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts` to your PATH and move it anywhere above `C:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip`. When you enter `pip` in PowerShell, cmd, or whatever else you're using, Windows will search all paths listed in PATH in top down order.

Comment: It works, but I'm just curious, why with `Python37\Scripts` and not just `Python37`?

Comment: The <code>Python37</code> folder contains just the python executable and the <code>Python37\Scripts</code> subfolder contains the pip executable. Whatever their reasoning, Microsoft has it so Windows only searches within the specific folders listed in your PATH, but not in any of their sub-directories.

Comment: ok, thanks! Also, just a helpful tip as you're new, stackoverflow uses "mini-markdown" for comments editing, which doesn't support HTML (unlike questions or answers). You can find some more information on how that works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).